# Google script to duplicate a tab then change formula to references the tab it was duplicated from

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with each tab being a week. I want to create consecutive tabs for the remaining weeks but I want column A to pull from the previous week. So column A would automatically change to reference the week prior.

instead of manually creating a duplicate and changing formula in column A, I would like to find a script that creates tabs and changes the formula based on the previous weeks data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y-2mp4leVr3TO61q1ew1RcohdAsDqkmYyxe2XGYJxnw/edit#gid=516240205

Comment: Can you please share a sample output you would like to achieve? If you could provide it in a Spreadsheet it would be perfect.

Comment: @Alessandro I linked an example sheet of what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

Your task could be summed up in this subtasks:

1. retrieve the dates
2. for each date create a new sheet with the date as title/name
3. insert the reference to the previous sheet as a Google Sheet Formula in a desired cell/range

### Retrieve the dates

I would proceed to get the values contained in the desired range of the `Dates` Sheet and save them in an array.

```
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let dates = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A14").getValues();
```

### Build the new Sheets & inserting the previous Sheet reference as Formula

I can use the `Array.map()` method to loop through each date and use it as argument for the `.inserSheet(sheetName: string)` method.

I will use a support variable `previousSheetName` to keep track of the previous sheet name during the loop.

In my test scenario this variable is initialized with an extra Sheet's name. In this Sheet I inserted the Column values I want in the first generated Sheet.

With the `.setFormula()` method I will enter a the Formula that references the previous Sheet.

Finally, I will update my support variable with the just created Sheet's name.

```
  var previousSheetName = "SourceColumn";
  dates.map(date => {
            let d = new Date(date);
            let sheet = ss.insertSheet(d.toLocaleDateString()); // I will format the date to a DateString to get rid of the timezone and timestamp.
            sheet.getRange(1,1).setFormula(`='${previousSheetName}'!A1`);
            previousSheetName = d.toLocaleDateString()
   });
```

### References

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

[.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

[.insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname)

[.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)